# Passing a custom python function into a tornado template

Tags: python, tornado

I want to write a custom function and pass it unto my tornado template fine.

Like `def trimString(data): return data[0:20]` then push this into my tornado file.
This should allow me trim strings.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not [especially clear in the documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html?highlight=ui_methods#template-syntax), but you can do this easily by defining this function in a module and passing the module to `tornado.web.Application` as the `ui_methods` argument.

I. E.:

in ui_methods.py:

```
def trim_string(data):
    return data[0:20]
```

in app.py:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

import ui_methods

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("main.html")


urls = [(r"/", MainHandler)]
application = tornado.web.Application(urls, ui_methods=ui_methods)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

in main.html:

```
....
{{ trim_string('a string that is too long............') }}
....
```

Andy Boot's solution also works, but it's often nice to have functions like this automatically accessible in every template.

Comment: Thanks Cole, let me try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Cole, let me try this out and see how it goes.Cole pls can you add a code sample, the one you added above isn't that helpful. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've tried to clarify further; it's helpful if you can say what's unclear about it.

Comment: Apparently now your example `trim_string` method will always receive handler as the first argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can import functions in Tornado. I think this is the cleanest solution.
At the top of your template simply do the following:

```
{% import lib %}
```

later you can do

```
{{ trim_string(data)}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also pass the function in as a template variable like this:

```
 template_vars['mesage'] = 'hello'
 template_vars['function'] = my_function # Note: No ()

        self.render('home.html',
            **template_vars
        )
```

Then in your template you call it like this:

```
 {{ my_function('some string') }}
```