# Tornado templates setting value field

Tags: python, html, tornado

I have a python array:

```
a=["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

I pass this as a value to tornado render:

```
 self.render("index.html", a=a)
```

In my html I have the following:

```
  <input type="hidden" id="xxx" value="
  {% for c in a %}
     {{c}}
  {% end %}
  "/>
```

Which gives me the following messy output:

```
<input type="hidden" id="xxx" value="

a

b

c

d

e

f

"/>
```

I tried to use a {{c.strip()}} but that did the same thing. I also trying to mix in javascript however the javascript didn't execute after rendering to populate the value field. I want the html to be normal that is `value="a b c d e f"`

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Tornado's [filter_whitespace](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#tornado.template.filter_whitespace) feature, new in version 4.3.

```
  {% whitespace oneline %}
  <input type="hidden" id="xxx" value="{% for c in a %}
     {{c}}
  {% end %}"/>
  {% whitespace all %}
```

There will still be a few extra spaces but it's much closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jesse didn't know about that!

Answer (score 1):

Just join the list in the backend itself.

```
 self.render("index.html", a=' '.join(a))
```

And use,

```
<input type="hidden" id="xxx" value="{{ a }}" />
```

in template

Comment: Not a bad approach thanks. I would like to know if there's a  template way to do this too though

Comment: @xenophon or create a custom filter to join the list items by space. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13003440/3297613

Answer (score 0):

The same as @Avinash answered, only in-template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="xxx" value="{{ ' '.join(a) }}" />
```

Tornado templates, unlike some other templating engines like Django or Jinja, allows arbitrary Python expressions in the templates.